# Configure decorators with NServiceBus DI

Tags: dependency-injection, decorator, nservicebus, nservicebus3, property-injection

How can I configure NServiceBus to inject decorated classes correctly?

Imagine this scenario:

```
public class A
{
    public IDependency Dependency {get;set;}
}

public class B : IDependency
{
    public IDependency DecoratedDependency {get; set;}
}

public class C : IDependency{}
```

I want to set up my config so that `B` is created with `C` injected, and then `A` is created with `B` injected.  I don't want `A` created with `C` injected.

How do I set the config up so that it does this?  It feels like I should use something along the lines of:

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer
    .ConfigureComponent<B>(...)
    .ConfigureProperty(x=>x.DecoratedDependency, instanceOfCFromTheContainer);
Configure.Instance.Configurer
     .ConfigureComponent<A>(...)
     .ConfigureProperty(x=>x.Dependency, instanceOfBFromTheContainer);
```

but I'm not sure how I refer to those instances?  And how do I ensure that `C` is only used for `B`'s property and that `B` is used everywhere else when the container does its resolution?

Or do I need to do something different?

Comment: Are you passing your container into NSB for it to use as well?  It may be better to use the native container configuration and then pass it in.

Comment: We are just using a series of calls to `Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<Blah>`.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'It may be better to use the native container configuration and then pass it in'.

Comment: Adam wants to know if you use a DIcontainer such as windsor, ninject... Or do you ise the DefaultBuilder? If you have Configure.With().NinjectBuilder(kernel) you can provide a kernal instance. It is much more powerful to do this kind of configuration on the native container as your are not restricted to a common container abstractions as NSB uses it internally.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  We are just using the default builder.  Can I not do this kind of configuration using the common container abstractions?

Comment: Not that I know. I suggest you use one of your favorite containers for that purpose